# how to give horizantal scrolling in tab controls using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My prob is : when i click the link button it open the window and when i click the window it going to add as tab,  now my problem is when it open in window page
is proper alignment when it going to add as a tab page alignment is different

Comment: post the relevant code, or a simplified example.

Comment: when i copy paste the code it shows an error can you give any other alternative solution so that i can attach the file...